# How to place check or tick mark in dialog if particular item (exists in horizontal layout) is selected

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-dialogfragment, android-dialog

I am trying to make custom dialog in which i want to make selection of textview and image visible if user is going to selection .

in below code i have given three text views and four image view, want that if user is going to select text view or image view it should be text color change and on image it should be tick mark should be appear.

like this attached image .

[attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/odGlX.png)

As per attached image i want to make selection if user select image it should appear as a tick mark and if user selects any text views then tick should below of the text views and color also changed.

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.cust);
        dialog.setTitle("Your title");
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.show();
        TextView d_btn_ok =      (TextView)     dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnOk);
        TextView d_btn_cancel = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnCancel);
        d_btn_ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        d_btn_cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        TextView tvMsg11 =(TextView)  dialog.findViewById(R.id.tvMsg11);


        TextView tvMsg111 =(TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.tvMsg111);
        TextView tvMsg1111 =(TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.tvMsg1111);

        ImageView image1 = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.image1);
        image1.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.one));


        ImageView image2 = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.image2);
        image2.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.two));
        ImageView image3 = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.image3);
        image3.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.three));
        ImageView image4 = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.image4);
        image4.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.four));
    }
}
```

cust.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="430dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"

    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvMsg"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"

        android:textSize="20sp"
android:textColor="#293448"
        android:text="Update your water intake" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvMsg1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvMsg"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="21.5dp"

        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textColor="#293448"

        android:text="How many glasses of water do you
drink daily?" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearImage21"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvMsg1"
        android:weightSum="3">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvMsg11"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="23.5dp"

            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="4 Glasses"
            android:textSize="14sp"/>


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvMsg111"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvMsg11"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"


            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="6 Glasses"
            android:textSize="14sp"/>



        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvMsg1111"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvMsg111"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"


            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="8 Glasses"
            android:textSize="14sp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearImage21"
        android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="21.5dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:textSize="16sp"

        android:text="Your container size?" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearImage1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/container"
        android:weightSum="4">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_button_background"

            android:checked="true"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"

            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image4"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>



   <!-- <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearImag2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearImage1"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image4"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


    </LinearLayout>-->

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearImage1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:weightSum="2"
     >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/btnOk"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:layout_marginLeft="86.5dp"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:text="CANCEL"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textColor="#293448" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/btnCancel"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="48.5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="16sp"

android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:text="SUBMIT"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textColor="#21c8d7" />

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

After apply above code

I am getting like this image

[this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Gpjt.png)

Answer (score 0):

We can do it easily as per attached image

Made visible when need of Highlighter under text views or adjacent of image.
or Made invisible when not need or pressed That's it .

Wrote code for same which is working  .

text color change on the basis of text selection  :

text_color.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

        <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#00b200"></item>
        <item android:state_focused="true" android:color="#00b200"/>
        <item android:state_selected="true" android:color="#000000"/>
        <item android:color="#d3d3d3"></item>

    </selector>
```

For Dialog :-

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.cust);
        dialog.setTitle("Your title");
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.show();

        TextView d_btn_ok =      (TextView)     dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnOk);
        TextView d_btn_cancel = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnCancel);
        d_btn_ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        d_btn_cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        final TextView tvMsg111 =(TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.tvMsg111);
        final TextView tvMsg1111=(TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.tvMsg1111);
        final TextView tvMsg11 = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.tvMsg11);
        ImageView tick5=(ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.tick5);
        ImageView tick6=(ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.tick6);
        ImageView tick7=(ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.tick7);
        tvMsg11.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

               // final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.image2);

                //tvMsg11.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tick));
                tvMsg111.setSelected(false);

                tvMsg1111.setSelected(false);


                tvMsg11.setSelected(true);

                tick5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                tick6.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                tick7.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            }
        });

        // final TextView tvMsg111 =(TextView)  dialog.findViewById(R.id.tvMsg111);
        tvMsg111.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                tvMsg11.setSelected(false);
                tvMsg1111.setSelected(false);
                tvMsg111.setSelected(true);

                tick6.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                tick7.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                tick5.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


            }
        });

        //final TextView tvMsg1111 =(TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.tvMsg1111);
        tvMsg1111.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                tvMsg11.setSelected(false);
                tvMsg111.setSelected(false);
                tvMsg1111.setSelected(true);


                tick7.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                tick6.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                tick5.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        });




        /*TextView tvMsg111 =(TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.tvMsg111);
        TextView tvMsg1111 =(TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.tvMsg1111);*/

        ImageView image1 = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.image1);
        ImageView tick1=(ImageView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.tick1);
        ImageView tick2=(ImageView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.tick2);
        ImageView tick3=(ImageView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.tick3);
        ImageView tick4=(ImageView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.tick4);
        image1.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.one));
        image1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                //final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.image2);

                tick1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                tick2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                tick3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                tick4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
               /* imageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tick));
                imageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.two));*/
            }
        });

        ImageView image2 = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.image2);
        // ImageView image21 = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.drawable.four);
// for replacing image on click of image
        image2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                //final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.image2);


                tick2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                tick1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                tick3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                tick4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
               /* imageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tick));
                imageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.two));*/
            }
        });
        image2.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.two));
        ImageView image3 = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.image3);
        image3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                //final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.image2);


                tick3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                tick1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                tick2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                tick4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

               /* imageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tick));
                imageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.two));*/
            }
        });

        image3.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.three));
        ImageView image4 = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.image4);
        image4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                //final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.image2);


                tick4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                tick1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                tick2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                tick3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
               /* imageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tick));
                imageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.two));*/
            }
        });

        image4.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.four));
```

cust.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="430dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"

        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvMsg"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"

            android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textColor="#293448"
            android:text="Update your water intake" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvMsg1"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tvMsg"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="21.5dp"

            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textColor="#293448"

            android:text="How many glasses of water do you
    drink daily?" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearImage21"

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tvMsg1"
            android:weightSum="3">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvMsg11"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="23.5dp"
                android:textColor="@drawable/text_color"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="4 Glasses"

                android:textSize="14sp"/>


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvMsg111"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvMsg11"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textColor="@drawable/text_color"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="6 Glasses"
                android:textSize="14sp"/>



            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvMsg1111"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvMsg111"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:textColor="@drawable/text_color"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="8 Glasses"
                android:textSize="14sp"/>
            </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/lineartick"

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/linearImage21"
            android:weightSum="3">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/tick5"
                android:layout_width="16dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/texthiglighter"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
                android:layout_height="10dp" />


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/tick6"
                android:layout_width="16dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.7"
                android:src="@drawable/texthiglighter"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image1"
                android:layout_height="10dp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/tick7"
                android:layout_width="16dp"
                android:layout_weight="1.3"
                android:src="@drawable/texthiglighter"
                android:visibility="invisible"

                android:layout_height="10dp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_below="@+id/linearImage21"
            android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="21.5dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textColor="#293448"
            android:alpha="80"
            android:text="Your container size?" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearImage1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/container"
            android:weightSum="4">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:checked="true"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/tick1"
                android:layout_width="13dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.1"
                android:src="@drawable/tick"
                android:layout_marginLeft="0.1dp"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image1"
                android:layout_height="13dp" />


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"

                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
           <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/tick2"
                android:layout_width="13dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.1"
                android:src="@drawable/tick"
               android:layout_marginLeft="0.1dp"
               android:visibility="invisible"
               android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image2"
               android:layout_height="13dp" />



            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image3"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/tick3"
                android:layout_width="13dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.1"
                android:src="@drawable/tick"
                android:layout_marginLeft="0.1dp"
              android:visibility="invisible"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image3"
                android:layout_height="13dp" />


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image4"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"

                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/tick4"
                android:layout_width="13dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.1"
                android:src="@drawable/tick"
                android:layout_marginLeft="0.1dp"
                android:visibility="invisible"
               android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image4"
                android:layout_height="13dp" />


        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearscale"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/linearImage1"
            android:weightSum="4">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/onne"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:textColor="#283d65"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="150 ML"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textSize="14sp"/>



            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/twoe"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"

                android:textColor="#283d65"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="250 ML"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textSize="14sp"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/three"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"

                android:textColor="#283d65"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="500 ML"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textSize="14sp"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/foure"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
                android:textColor="#283d65"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="1 LTR"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textSize="14sp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/viewp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:alpha="4"
            android:background="#000000"
            android:layout_below="@+id/linearscale"></View>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/linearscale"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
            android:weightSum="2"
         >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/btnOk"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#fff"
                android:layout_marginLeft="86.5dp"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:text="CANCEL"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textColor="#293448" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/btnCancel"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="48.5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="16sp"

    android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
                android:background="#fff"
                android:text="SUBMIT"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textColor="#21c8d7" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```